# How to identify the same className by the CSS Module when they aren't in the same CSS file by css-module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a main CSS file `style.styl`, with the container:

```css
.container
  // ...
```

I have another CSS file `components.styl` for some React components, and these must be inside the container

```css
.container
  .componentA
    // ...
  .componentB
    // ...
```

And then after built by Webpack and CSS module with the following configuration:

```js
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    modules: {
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[contenthash:5]',
    },
  },
},
```

the `.container` in `style.styl` will be compiled to `style__container__8cc45`

the `.container` in `components.styl` will compiled to `components__container__45aeb`

Now how can I identify the container to the same name with [contenthash:5]

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. The main idea of css modules is to have unique separate name of class for module, so you do not need nesting of css rules. If you need it explicitly, do not do it in 2 files, put all your code of these 2 modules in single (css module) file.

Comment: @lavor, because I want the components must be inside the `container`. I add some reset style for the `container`, such as `container.*`.

Comment: These components are programmed by other engineers, so I want to apply the reset styles for their components (and they must be in the `container` scope)

Comment: Now I understand the problem. I think it is not possible to reference css module from another. See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587507/css-modules-referencing-classes-from-other-modules#answer-42588939

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @lavor

I found a solution to the problem (maybe not elegant)

```js
// ...
loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
options: {
  importLoaders: 1,
  modules: {
    calIdentName: '[local]__[contenthash:5]',
    getLocalIdent: (loaderContext, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
      if (!options.context) {
        options.context = loaderContext.rootContext;
      }

      let request = null;
      if (localName === 'container') {
        // do not change the value of `request` when localName is 'container'
        request = 'src/assets/css/style.styl';
      } else {
        request = path
            .relative(options.context, loaderContext.resourcePath)
            .replace(/\\/g, '/');
      }

      options.content = `${options.hashPrefix + request}+${localName}`;
      localIdentName = localIdentName.replace(/\[local\]/gi, localName);
      const hash = loaderUtils.interpolateName(
        loaderContext,
        localIdentName,
        options
      );
      return hash
        .replace(new RegExp('[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-_\u00A0-\uFFFF]', 'g'), '-')
        .replace(/^((-?[0-9])|--)/, '_$1');
    },
  },
},
// ...
```